# Injecting DynamoDbMapper using Dagger - AwsMobileClient

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, dagger-2, aws-mobilehub

I'm struggling to find a way to use dagger to inject a DynamoDB mapper into my Repository.

I'm using `AwsMobileClient` which requires initialising in my "main activity" like so:

```
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(application) {
        Timber.d("AWSMobileClient is initialized")
    }.execute()
```

Currently I'm creating a mapper inline in my repository like so:

```
    val credentials = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentialsProvider
    val config = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration
    val ddbClient = AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials)
    ddbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2))
    val mapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
            .awsConfiguration(config)
            .dynamoDBClient(ddbClient)
            .build()
```

If i move that out to a dagger module it looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
AmazonDynamoDBClient provideDynamoDbClient() {
    return new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
}

@Singleton
@Provides
DynamoDBMapper provideDynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient) {
    return DynamoDBMapper.builder()
            .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
            .dynamoDBClient(ddbClient)
            .build();
}
```

However this crashes and burns because dagger tries to create the objects before the `AwsMobileClient` has finished initialising and the credentials provider is null when trying to create the `DynamoDBClient`

Not sure if i'm going about this the wrong way and all the samples don't use dependency injection so can't steal ideas from there.